# Transfer ownership to caller and re-instantiate field

Tags: rust

I want to implement a reset method (in an unrelated struct) that reinstantiates a field (`Record` struct), and transfer the ownership of previous value to the caller:

```
pub struct Record {
    pub raw_content: String,
    pub fields: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

```
fn pub reset(&mut self) -> Record {
  let record = self.record;
  self.record = Record::new();
  return record;
}
```

However, when I try to do this, the compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.record` which is behind a mutable reference
  --> src/parser.rs:45:22
   |
45 |         let record = self.record;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.record` has type `Record`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
45 |         let record = &self.record;
   |                      +
```

I don't want to borrow the object; I want to give it up to the caller then re-initialize field. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html).

```rust
use std::mem::replace;

pub fn reset(&mut self) -> Record {
  return replace(&mut self.record, Record::new());
}
```

Comment: If `Record` implements `Default`, you can also use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html).